# Is partitioned column always required to be added to the query to scan the partitions?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, database-performance, database-partitioning

I had partitioned my table in azure sql by referring below doc.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2888/how-to-partition-an-existing-sql-server-table/

I need to know that whether the partitioned column should be always used in the where clause of the select query to scan through partition or direct select will achieve that?

Comment: When the partitioning column is not specified as a predicate, all partitions will be touched but not necessarily scanned. The query plan which indexes are used and how. It is best to specify the partitioning column so that only needed partitions are accessed.

Comment: Is all partitions will be touched means "Query will be executed as like before partition the table"?

Comment: In the case of a scan, a full scan of each partition will be needed without partition elimination. The scans will probably perform similarly to the non-partitioned table. In the case of a seek without elimination, a seek will be needed for each partition, which will likely be slower than the non-partitioned table.

Comment: Since I'm new to these topics, I need more info. So from your point what I understand is without including partitioned column, scan operation will be similar to the non-partitioned table whereas seek operation will be slower that non-partitioned table. Is this correct? Also can you please give some references to learn the diff b/w seek and scan?

Comment: Your understanding of my comment is correct. A good resource for understanding the difference between an index scan and seeks as well as execution plans in general is [Grant Fritchey's SQL Server Execution Plans eBook](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/books/sql-server-execution-plans-third-edition-by-grant-fritchey/). I suggest you peruse it, although it doesn't specifically include table partitioning. Be aware that table partitioning is mostly a manageability feature where one needs to understand the implications in order to avoid negatively impacting performance.